# not able to login to admin: custom user model

Tags: django

I can authenticate using the command line

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> user = authenticate(username='shiva@gmail.com',password='123456')
>>> user
<Employee: shiva@gmail.com>
>>>
```

but I am not able login using the url : http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

showing following error:

> Please enter the correct email address and password for a staff
>   account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.

model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (BaseUserManager,AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin)

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, date_of_birth, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Employee(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=None)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = MyUserManager()
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']
```

Comment: add your custom login code

Answer (score 0):

I think the user is not a `superuser` or `staff` user for which you are using username and password to login to adminsite. Try to create a new user using `python manage.py createsuperuser`, and use that to login into adminsite. Also you can assign admin status to user `shiva@gmail.com` from shell(`python manage.py shell`). Like this:

```
from <your_app>.models import Employee

shiva = Employee.objects.get(email='shiva@gmail.com')
shiva.is_superuser = True
shiva.is_staff = True

shiva.save()
```

Then use this user to login to adminsite.